# Impossible to get html element(s) using multiple classes with Selenium VBA

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I can't get to an element present on an HTML page with a Selenium command. I tried everything: find with Class, Id and CSS, but nothing works. Maybe with the Path search method, but not knowing it, I can't formulate it. Can anyone help me?

This is the HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="search" value="" placeholder="Cerca per prodotto" class="form-control input-lg searchInputHeader">
```

I expect to be able to enter a value located on an Excel sheet in the search field on the HTML page, using the `.SendKeys` instruction.

For example:

```
.FindElementsByClass("form-control input-lg searchInputHeader").SendKeys Cells(4, VbaPosizione)
```

but doesnt'work.

Comment: the class  in sendKeys is not the same that you have in the HTML.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The instruction with sandKey must be exactly : .FindElementsByClass("form-control input-lg searchInputHeader").SendKeys Cells(4, VbaPosizione), but dosn't work.

Comment: Could it because you are using the version with an extra "s" which gives you multiple elements. (ie. FindElementsByClass instead of FindElementByClass) ?

Comment: Dosn't work also with FindElementByClass

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into the "Compound class names not permitted error". This means that `FindElementsByClass` only accepts one class name.

If you want to select an element using multiple class names, you could to use a CSS selector like this (with a dot as prefix and no space between the different class names):

```
.FindElementByCss(".form-control.input-lg.searchInputHeader")
```

Also, a good pratice to debug you code is to split the step in multiple lines. For instance you could do the Selection and SendKeys seperatly:

```
    Dim MyInput As WebElement
    Set MyInput = MyWebDriver.FindElementByCss(".form-control.input-lg.searchInputHeader")
    MyInput.SendKeys "Some text"
```