# VBA Webscrape URL from HTML (src="")

Tags: excel, vba, image, web-scraping, excel-2019

I tried to combine code parts i could make work, but it was working with <span>, <meta> but it is not working with <img>
Can anyone help to make it work?

I try to get:
https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt34360a0ffaff7811/11015_alt.png?fit=bounds&format=png&width=800&height=800&dpr=1
From this code:

```
<img src="https://www.lego.com/cdn/cs/set/assets/blt34360a0ffaff7811/11015_alt.png?fit=bounds&amp;format=png&amp;width=800&amp;height=800&amp;dpr=1" alt="" class="Imagestyles__Img-sc-1qqdbhr-0 cajeby">
```

[Code part where i want to get the Src url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80CEY.jpg)

```
Sub picgrab()

  Dim Doc As Object  
  Dim nodeAllPic As Object
  Dim nodeOnePic As Object
  Dim pic As Object

  Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlFile")

  With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
  
    url = "https://www.lego.com/hu-hu/product/around-the-world-11015"
    .Open "GET", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
    .send
' It is important that i can't use InternetExplorer.

'This should work i guess, but it skips after 'For Each' line.
    Set nodeAllPic = Doc.getElementsByClassName("Imagestyles__Img-sc-1qqdbhr-0 cajeby")

    For Each nodeOnePic In nodeAllPic
        If nodeOnePic.getAttribute("class") = "Imagestyles__Img-sc-1qqdbhr-0 cajeby" Then
           Set pic = nodeOneVip.getElementsByClassName("Imagestyles__Img-sc-1qqdbhr-0 cajeby")(0)
           ActiveCell.Value = pic.getAttribute("src")
        
        End If
    Next nodeOnePic
  
  End With
  
End Sub
```

I tired the code above and modified it many way, but couldn't get the content of Src="" .

Comment: If you only need the first image, you can also read the URL from a meta tag `<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.lego.com/c...` The URLs for all images are in the JSON contained in the HTML file. We have already briefly discussed the JSON in your other question. @DecimalTurn 's answer contains a different solution. However, I assume that in order to be able to implement one of the two, you will have to deal with it a lot.

Comment: @Zwenn 
Thank you, that was a good suggestion. 
After the other example I could easily implement it into my program and it worked great :) .

Comment: @Zwenn 
It would be interesting to know which method (selenium or your's) would be faster for the program as I have about 700 links to go through automatically, and for each lego set, I will collect datas from other sites as well, not just lego.com.

Comment: @Zwenn 
You are right, I need to practice a lot to get more and more practise in this area of web scraping.
Other sites may present new challenges that may stuck me and I'll try to find a solution myself, but thanks for making this stackoverflow very useful.  I guess i will have other questions :)

Answer (score 0):

### Need to write the response

First of all, you never write the HTML response to your `htmlfile` object. So you won't be able to find anything when you call the method `getElementsByClassName` on it.

Make sure that you include the following line before trying to use the `Doc` object:

```
Doc.Write .responseText
```

### Dynamic Content

Secondly, some of the content on that page is not in the original HTTP request that `XMLHTTP` receives. The page contains JavaScript code that loads content dynamically.

To test this in Chrome, you can open the Chrome DevTools window on that page, then [disable JavaScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/disable/) and refresh the page.

You'll then see the original HTML and a notification that says that JavaScript is disabled.

[image]

And now, if you search inside the Elements tab, you won't find the element you were looking for (at least I couldn't find anything with a class "cajeby").

### Browser emulation

So, now what? Well, you'll need to use an object to manipulate the original response to execute the JavaScript code. For that you could use [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/overview/). It's the modern way of doing web scraping or any browser automation with VBA.

You can easily find tutorials on how to get started with Selenium for VBA, but I would recommend this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FoxWcvZzYVk) by WiseOwlTutorials.

Then your code could look like this:

```
    Dim Browser As New Selenium.WebDriver
    Browser.Start "chrome", "https://www.lego.com/hu-hu/product/around-the-world-11015"
    Browser.Get "/"
    
    Dim img As WebElement
    Set img = Browser.FindElementByCss(".Imagestyles__Img-sc-1qqdbhr-0.cajeby", timeout:=5000)
    
    Debug.Print img.Attribute("src")
    
    Set Browser = Nothing
```

##### Some notes on the code

- Make sure that you have included a reference to the Selenium Library
- Notice the use of `FindElementByCss`. This is necessary because you are using 2 class names and no other method currently support that, but you'll need to use the CSS selector syntax. (More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75036118/5958842)).
- Notice the use of `timeout:=5000` that lets Selenium know that you are willing to wait up to 5000 milliseconds for the JavaScript code to load the content you are looking for (More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34942084/5958842)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed reply!

This selenium is an interesting topic. I can see that if I want to collect data from many different sites, it might be easier to use in the long run. I will definitely check out the tutorial videos. Thank you!